# In iOS 7, setting delegate of UITextField inside UISearchBar seems to break both. How can I get both delegates to respond?

Tags: delegates, ios7, uitextfield, uisearchbar, uitextfielddelegate

I have a search bar which filters contacts as the user types, but I also need to access the text field directly in case they type a name that is not in the address book. So, I need to have both UISearchBarDelegate and UITextFieldDelegate working at the same time.

In iOS 6 this worked fine. In iOS 7, once I find the search bar text field and set its delegate, everything breaks. The keyboard no longer responds, no text appears, etc.

This is the code when the view appears:

```
UITextField *searchBarTextField = nil;
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [mySearchBar subviews]) {
    if ( [searchBarSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class] ] ) {
        // ios 6 and earlier
        searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)searchBarSubview;
    } else {
        // for ios 7 what we need is nested inside another container
        for (UIView *subSubView in [searchBarSubview subviews]) {
            if ( [subSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class] ] ) {
                searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)subSubView;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (searchBarTextField) {
    [searchBarTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
    // TODO: in ios 7, setting this breaks everything. search stops working, search keyboard no longer responds, nothing.
    [searchBarTextField setDelegate:self];
}
```

I am at a loss. Anyone know how to get this working in iOS 7? Thanks.

Comment: Having same issue.. Please reply if someone finds the soltuion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found an ugly solution, **created an Done button in the accessory view, on the top of the keyboard**. Better then nothing.

[image]

```
for(UIView *subView in _searchBar.subviews) {

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {

        for (UIView *subSubView in subView.subviews) {

            if([subSubView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
                UITextField *textField = subSubView;
                UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
                UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(done:)];
                toolbar.items = @[done];
                textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
                _theTextField = textField;
            }
        }
    } else {

        if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            UITextField *textField = subView;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            textField.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}

- (void)done:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    [self textFieldShouldReturn:_theTextField];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *searchSubs in searchBar.subviews){
    for (id searchSub in searchSubs.subviews) {
        if ([searchSub conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]){
            [(UITextField *)searchSub setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
            [(UITextField *)searchSub setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
            [(UITextField *)searchSub setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a scope issue setting the delegate to the UITextField after the subview loop. Try setting the delegate inside the loop instead:

```
    UITextField *searchBarTextField = nil;
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [mySearchBar subviews]) {
    if ( [searchBarSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class] ] ) {
        // ios 6 and earlier
        searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)searchBarSubview;
        searchBarTextField.delegate = self;
    } else {
        // for ios 7 what we need is nested inside another container
        for (UIView *subSubView in [searchBarSubview subviews]) {
            if ( [subSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class] ] ) {
                searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)subSubView;
                searchBarTextField.delegate = self;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (searchBarTextField) {
    [searchBarTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
}
```